# Accessing the XML string value

Tags: xml, perl

I am using the linked API to access the user profile.

```
my $profile_xml = $li->request(
    request_url         => 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)',
    access_token        => $access_token->{token},
    access_token_secret => $access_token->{secret},
);
```

The profile_xml parsed and put in the data dumper and printed

```
$VAR1 = [ 'person', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, 'bEdS5KlaV7' ], 0, ' ' ] ];
```

The above value is got from xml string by using the data dumper. i want to access the id `bEdS5KlaV7`. How can i access the id and store in one variable for process.

Comment: Possible duplicates by same user:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717426/accesing-the-xml-string-values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711097/retrieve-values-from-the-reponse-xml-by-getgetelementbythetagname
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670193/how-to-print-the-profile-details-individual-lines

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $VAR1 = [ 'person', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, 'bEdS5KlaV7' ], 0, ' ' ] ];
print $VAR1->[1]->[4]->[2], "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
bEdS5KlaV7
```

See also: [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Can you tell the three array position in the above var1, because i want to add some other fields.

Comment: Sorry for that, And now i am understood  how to do thanks for the concern.